# XAER_OUTSIDE Exception - Spring 4.0.3 - Hibernate 4.1.12 - JTA - Websphere 8 - DB2

Tags: spring, hibernate, db2, jta, websphere-8

**EDIT** - I have checked this combinations so it seems there's something wrong with Hibernate 4:

- Spring 4 + JPA + Hibernate 4 -> Exception
- Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 -> Exception
- Spring 4 + JPA + Hibernate 3 -> OK
- Spring 4 + Hibernate 3 -> OK
- Spring 3 + JPA - Hibernate 4 -> Exception
- Spring 3 + JPA - Hibernate 3 -> OK
- Spring 3 + Hibernate 3 -> OK

I have recently upgraded an application from Spring 3.2/Hibernate 3.6.10 to Spring 4.0.3 + Hibernate 4.1.12. My environment is IBM Websphere 8.0.0.7 and DB2 and the application is configured to use a XA Datasource.

The point is that **at the first database call** (subsequent calls are always OK) I am getting this error:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Foo loadFoo(int id) {
    LOG.debug("load {}", id);
    FooEntity fe = fooDAO.findOne(id);
    ...
}

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fooRestController'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalControllerAdvice'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Invoking WebSphere UOW action: type=1, join=false
org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource DEBUG - Adding transactional method 'findOne' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Invoking WebSphere UOW action: type=1, join=true
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils DEBUG - Opening JPA EntityManager
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl DEBUG - Skipping JTA sync registration due to auto join checking
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl DEBUG - successfully registered Synchronization
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl DEBUG - Looking for a JTA transaction to join
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils DEBUG - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
org.hibernate.loader.Loader DEBUG - Loading entity: [com.mycompany.spring4.entity.FooEntity#17027]
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl DEBUG - Obtaining JDBC connection
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl DEBUG - Obtained JDBC connection
DSRA0304E:  XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are: "".
DSRA0302E:  XAException occurred.  Error code is: XAER_OUTSIDE (-9).  Exception is: XAER_OUTSIDE
J2CA0027E: An exception occurred while invoking start on an XA Resource Adapter from DataSource jdbc/LOCDBD1_XA, within transaction ID {XidImpl: formatId(57415344), gtrid_length(36), bqual_length(54),
data(0000014517a4c063000000015e7f81b4c90865e6b88e167905e5d2ed67f44ed6409cba5c0000014517a4c063000000015e7f81b4c90865e6b88e167905e5d2ed67f44ed6409cba5c000000010000000000000000000000000001)} : com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.zh: XAER_OUTSIDE

Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: XAResource working outside transaction
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.startRes(RegisteredResources.java:1019)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:1113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:2214)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.enlist(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.enlist(XATransactionWrapper.java:727)
    ... 140 more
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.zh: XAER_OUTSIDE
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bc.a(bc.java:1651)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bc.start(bc.java:1530)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.start(WSRdbXaResourceImpl.java:1525)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.start(XATransactionWrapper.java:1475)
    at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.JTAResourceBase.start(JTAResourceBase.java:153)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.startRes(RegisteredResources.java:1002)
    ... 144 more
```

This is the log trace of the second and successful call :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fooRestController'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'globalControllerAdvice'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Invoking WebSphere UOW action: type=1, join=false
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Invoking WebSphere UOW action: type=1, join=true
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils DEBUG - Opening JPA EntityManager
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl DEBUG - Skipping JTA sync registration due to auto join checking
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl DEBUG - successfully registered Synchronization
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl DEBUG - Looking for a JTA transaction to join
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils DEBUG - Registering transaction synchronization for JPA EntityManager
org.hibernate.loader.Loader DEBUG - Loading entity: [com.mycompany.spring4.entity.FooEntity#17027]
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl DEBUG - Obtaining JDBC connection
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl DEBUG - Obtained JDBC connection
org.hibernate.loader.Loader DEBUG - Result set row: 0
org.hibernate.loader.Loader DEBUG - Result row: EntityKey[com.mycompany.spring4.entity.FooEntity#17027]
org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad DEBUG - Resolving associations for [com.mycompany.spring4.entity.FooEntity#17027]
org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad DEBUG - Done materializing entity [com.mycompany.spring4.entity.FooEntity#17027]
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl DEBUG - Releasing JDBC connection
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl DEBUG - Released JDBC connection
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler DEBUG - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
org.hibernate.loader.Loader DEBUG - Done entity load
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Returned from WebSphere UOW action: type=1, join=true
org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils DEBUG - Closing JPA EntityManager
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl DEBUG - Aggressively releasing JDBC connection
org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager DEBUG - Returned from WebSphere UOW action: type=1, join=false
```

The relevant part of my cfg is:

```
<bean id="mainEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mainPersistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="mainDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" ref="packages-mainEntityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransactionFactory</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven order="0" />

<bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager">
    <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Any idea why it fails the first time it's called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved by itself upgrading to Spring 4.1.6 and Hibernate 4.2.19. I guess it was a Hibernate-related issue.